# iPhone SDK 4 The version of iPhone OS on “” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode3.2

Right,

I am running XCode 3.2.3 with the iPhone 4 SDK.  I have paid apple and enrolled, added my certificates and provisioning profiles. Now, I have plugged my iPod into Xcode and clicked "Use for development". My iPhone is running iOS 4.1 and Xcode says -

> The version of iPhone OS on “” does
>   not match any of the versions of
>   iPhone OS supported for development
>   with this installation of the iPhone
>   SDK. Please restore the device to a
>   version of the OS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the
>   iPhone SDK; which is available here.
>
> ```
> OS Installed on ....
> 4.1 (8B117)
>
> Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
> 4.0.2
> 4.0.1
> 4.0
> 3.2.2
> 3.2.1
> 3.2
> 3.1.3
> 3.1.2
> 3.1.1
> 3.1
> 3.0.1
> 3.0
> ```

So do I need to download the whole XCode and iPhone SDK package again?

Will updating the SDK screw with my app?

Cheers!

Comment: its annoying isn't it? You can't just download the SDK unfortunately, you have to re-download all 3gb of xcode! :p

Comment: Ridiculous, this is going to take ages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your XCode to latest version. Along with that iOS will be upgraded to 4.1 automatically.
your app won't get screwed up.

Comment: I assume my developer certificates and profiles won't disappear, because it took forever to add them.

Comment: No, they won't disappear. But still adding certificates/profiles is not at all a big task if you understand them properly.